# Get Modis tile from lat long

Tags: tiles, modis

I'm trying to get the MODIS tile that I need, I can get it using online calculator http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/developer/tilemap.cgi but I need to get it in code.

How I can convert lat, long to MOD09A1 H/V tile?

Comment: Please check the answer to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71331/how-to-determine-latitude-longitude-point-from-a-pixel-within-a-modis-tile